# Always Encryption in Azure SQL ( Client Side Encryption)

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, always-encrypted

I've Implemented Always Encryption method in my Project, after knowing that it encrypts's the data in Client Side Code and Never reveals the Data to DataBase Engine.

I've gone through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider) and got a Clear Idea that Encryption/Decryption is done in Client Level(Driver).

Also, I've already posted a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040300/is-always-encrypted-method-encrypts-datas-the-before-movinginserting-into-azu) on this site too and got the Same Answers.

Although, I've needed to prove it to my Officials that between the Database Call and Client Code the data's will be encrypted.They simply ignore the Documentation.

How should I've able to prove them that during the network between the client and SQL server the Data in Encrypted and not Decrypted?

I tried with Process monitor. But it does not seem to work, it listing all the process behind the Visual Studio Execution(mostly DLL Calls)

Can i use Fiddler to Monitor ?

Comment: Run a network trace (e.g. Wireshark) on the client or server.

Comment: Use WireShark to check weather The Data Encrypted  OR NOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL profiler that can be accessed through SSMS.
You can find it in SSMS menu as Tools -> Sql Server Profiler.
With some google search, you can find resources on how to use it.

I would create two tables having the same schema. Encrypt a couple of columns of one of the tables using Always Encrypted.
Run select, insert and point lookup queries for each table. You will see that for table with Always Encrypted columns, you will see encrypted values being sent to SQL Server for the encrypted columns whereas for plaintext table all the values sent to the server will be in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Profiler is a good way to Prove the Data is Encrypted through-out the Network.I've tried with Fiddler as well as SQL Profile. Both Proved my data were encrypted through out the Channel between Client and SQL Server. I would like to Show Images on this. (May be helpful for others)

**Fiddler** *(Client Network Traffic)*
[image]

**SQL-Profiler** (Data's from Client to SQL Server as Encrypted)

[image]