# How to encrypt data which will not be decryptable by the developers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I need to encrypt credit card no in a way that nobody can view the actual no. Moreover, I don't want to store my encryption key information in SQL Server

Comment: if the developers are not sysadmin's on the box,this can work

Comment: _no body can view_ - who are "nobody"? Admins, developers, users?

Comment: no body means no one.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Data Masking may be used in this scenario. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dynamic-data-masking-get-started).

Hope this helps.

Comment: even thought the link may answer the question,it's a good practice to share some content from the link which can answer the question..Link only answers are not encouraged

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try on **[Azure Always Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine).**

It has the following benefits:

1. Through out the network, the Data's will be encrypted.(I've Provided an Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116028/always-encryption-in-azure-sql-client-side-encryption))
2. As you mention, storing encrypted key in SQL-Server is not a good practice at all. In Azure Always Encryption, you have a flexibility to store your Encryption key in various Locations like *MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE* ,*MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER*,*MSSQL_CNG_STORE*,*Azure_Key_Vault*(Even you can create your own custom key store provider too)- Find the details [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-column-master-key-transact-sql)
3. It can support in Azure-SQL and also On-Premises SQL Server (Starting from 2016)