# MS SQL 2016 PHP Always Encrypted

Tags: pdo, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

Might be early days for this - Does anyone have a PHP example of connecting to an MS SQL 2016 database, and retrieving an "Always Encrypted" column, de-crypted in plain text? I can retrieve the binary encrypted columns without problem (PDO or ODBC), but not the plain text version. Inserting/Updating an "Always Encrypted" column would be handy too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ODBC driver this connection string

```
SQLWCHAR *connString = L"Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server={myServer};Trusted_Connection=yes;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;";
```

should retrieve plaintext data for you, assuming that have access to the key. Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver) article should be useful for you.

For inserting/updating data in always encrypted columns, you can use [SSMS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/), [.Net application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/06/04/getting-started-with-always-encrypted/), or [ODBC application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver)

If you have additional questions please post them in the comments sections and I will try my best to help.

Comment: Thanks! For the "access to the key" part I had to set up and use a local server user (as opposed to an SQL user)

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are trying to convey using this sentence "For the "access to the key" part I had to set up and use a local server user (as opposed to an SQL user) " Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I tried to access my database, in PHP, using an SQL user and password. I couldn't seem to get this SQL user to be allowed access to the key. When I used a local server user (e.g. myserver\User1) instead, it worked fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where is your column master key certificate is stored? Also, the following answer might help you, I have explained briefly how the server-client setup should look like for always encrypted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157845/always-encrypted-behavior-in-sql-server-2016/42235099#42235099